# How to get to "Manage Subscriptions" from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any method to get to Manage Subscriptions in settings by clicking a button from my app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access the settings app from inside a sandboxed app -- i.e. any apps but Apple's -- without using a private API.

Answer (score 8):

you can open Subscription section of AppStore by opening this link in iphone/ipad safari:

```
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
```

or simply use this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]];
```

Doing this will first open safari, then will redirect it to Appstore subscriptions.

**EDIT:**

Replace `https` with `itms-apps` will open *subscriptions* directly

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 15, you can now use:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
    Task {
        do {
            try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window)
        }
    }
}
```

As documented here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions